# How do you find the area of the shaded (gray) region of the square not getting overlapped by the circle or triangle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles, area, angle

[image]

How do you find the area of the gray region in the problem.
Pretty much the isosceles triangle is 2" tall and 2" wide at the bottom.
The circle has a radius of 1"
The square is 2" tall and 2" wide.

My question is: How do you find the area of the shaded (gray) region of the square not getting overlapped by the circle or triangle.

Comment: The same question is [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1532853/how-to-find-area-of-remaining-square-with-shapes-inside/1532906#1532906)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $S$ be the square $C$ the circle and $T$ the triangle. What you look for is:
$$
|S \setminus (C\cup T)| = |S| - |C\cup T| = |S| - (|C| + |T| - |C\cap T|). 
$$

Let's consider $C\cap T$. $T$ is an isosceles triangle, and the angle on the top vertex is
$$
2\alpha = \arctan \frac 1 2.
$$
The region $C\cap T$ is the union of a circle sector of amplitude $4\alpha$ with two isosceles triangles with angle $\alpha$ at the bases and equal sides of length $1$. The circle sector has area $2\alpha$ and the triangles together have area $2\cos\alpha \sin\alpha$. So
$$
  |C \cap T| = 2\alpha + 2\sin\alpha\cos \alpha
   = 2\alpha +\frac{2\tan \alpha}{1+\tan^2 \alpha}
   = 2\arctan\frac 1 2 + \frac 2 5.
$$
and the grey area has measure
$$
4 - (\pi + 2 - (2\arctan \frac 1 2 + \frac 2 5))= \frac{12}{5} - \pi + 2\arctan \frac 1 2.
$$

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The area of the square surrounding the triangle and the circle is 4. The area of the triangle is $2*2*\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}$=$\sqrt{3}$. The area of the circle is $\pi$ because it has a diameter 2 and radius 1. The common region of the circle and the triangle is a sector of $60^\circ$ and the area is $\frac{60}{360}*\pi$ which equals to $\frac{\pi}{6}$. The area of the region not in the gray is $\sqrt{3}+\pi-\frac{\pi}{6}$. This needs to be subtracted from the area of the square, which is 4, to calculate the gray region, getting an answer of $\boxed{4-\sqrt{3}-\frac{5\pi}{6}}$. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked how rather than compute, I'll just describe the method:

- Take the square area,
- Remove the circle area,
- Compute the leftmost and rightmost red rectangular triangles limited by the triangle upper and lower border and the vertical axis as side border, remove both,
- Compute the two center areas limited by the triangle as lower border, the circle as upper border and the vertical axis as side border, remove both.